# Stream Video on mobile website without download

Tags: streaming, video, mobile-devices

Currently I'm linking to video files on my mobile site using an  tag linking to the appropriate format of the video depending on the handset. This is done via php.

iOS/Android > links to mp4
BB/Nokia > links to 3gp

I'm using a code similar to this

However, the user always receives the option of either playing the video or downloading it.

I'm currently linking to http:// urls and I would like the video to stream directly without allowing the user to save it?

Will it stream the videos directly if i setup and link to rspt urls or is there a way to link to video files using http:// protocol without allowing a download option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a player issue, if the player has the option to stream or save and supports and offers both options there's nothing you can do from the server end, you'd need to change or configure the player to only offer one option.

Comment: How can this be done? We're using the built in OS player. On Anroid, it gives us the option of 'videos' or 'internet'. On bb, its 'open' or 'save'

We'd like to directly stream.